# How to retrieve advanced SQL "where clause" to via checkbox group?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

Working in PHP, MySQL and HTML. Using Dreamweaver cs6.

Currently have an SQL statement :

```
SELECT tbl_disease.disease
FROM tbl_disease
INNER JOIN tbl_rel s1 ON (s1.diseaseID = tbl_disease.diseaseID)
INNER JOIN tbl_rel s2 ON (s2.diseaseID= tbl_disease.diseaseID)
WHERE
s1.symptomID= colname AND
s2.symptomID = colname2
```

The `s1.symptomID` and `s2.symptomID` are to be retrieved from check boxes that each pass and ID:

```
<label>
    <input  name="symptom" type="checkbox" id="symptom" value="1"  />
    Headache</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="symptom" value="2"  />
    Change in Bowel Habit</label>
  <br />
```

I'm going to include more than just two check boxes therefore the query will expand i.e. adding more joins s3, s4 etc. This works fine however I "MUST" fill out all the symptomID's for the query to work... This is a problem because what happens if the user just selects 1, 3 or 4 options (when I've added more of course), in other words all check boxes must be selected for it to work :-(. I  need the query to be dynamic but really have no idea how to achieve this?

The PHP:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_rsGetSymptoms = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['symptom'])) {
  $colname_rsGetSymptoms = $_POST['symptom'];
}
$colname2_rsGetSymptoms = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['symptom'])) {
  $colname2_rsGetSymptoms = $_POST['symptom'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_dbConn, $dbConn);
$query_rsGetSymptoms = sprintf("SELECT tbl_disease.disease FROM tbl_disease INNER JOIN tbl_rel s1 ON (s1.diseaseID = tbl_disease.diseaseID) INNER JOIN tbl_rel s2 ON (s2.diseaseID= tbl_disease.diseaseID) WHERE s1.symptomID= %s AND s2.symptomID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsGetSymptoms, "int"),GetSQLValueString($colname2_rsGetSymptoms, "int"));
$rsGetSymptoms = mysql_query($query_rsGetSymptoms, $dbConn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsGetSymptoms = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsGetSymptoms);
$totalRows_rsGetSymptoms = mysql_num_rows($rsGetSymptoms);
?>
```

This is the record set generated by dreamweaver.

I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time now, help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your are vulnerable to sql injection attacks, and you have absolutely no code that actually makes your query "dynamic" (and filling in a couple form fields doesn't count for that). You need to add a bunch of handling code to build more `join` clauses based on the presence/absence of the checkboxes.

Comment: hmm thanks, I'm quite new to all this. What your saying makes a lot of sense. I have already attempted to manually the code (without DW recordset). How would i add handling code though, would it be a bunch of if statements?

Comment: you build your query as a string. `$sql = "select ...";`, then use a bunch of `if()` stuff to add more stuff to that string. only when you're done checking/adding all those potential conditions do you actually do your `mysql_query()` call.

Comment: THANKS!, i did it that way and it seems to be working so far :-)